# AngularJS ng-click functions not working after I open print dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Here is very strange kind of error I am facing, I have a function which actually hides a div works fine if I don't open the print dialog, I have requirement to give print functionality for some data, but if I open the print dialog then the ng-click function is not working any more nothing happens and neither the browser shows any error in console. This is happening to all of my functions present on this page.

Here is my html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" title="Cancel Preview" ng-click="cancelPreview()">
  Cancel
</button>
```

and this is my AngularJS controller code:

```
 $scope.cancelPreview = function() {
        $scope.showInvoice = false;
 }
```

Comment: I did you mean about print dialog?

Comment: yes print dialog, when i open using javascript then any ng-click function is not working

Comment: and i am not able to perform any task on the page, until i refresh the page

Comment: Could you share your code in jsfiddle? i will try to reproduce...

Comment: ok i create and share the link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lufamvx2/1/ kindly check here, i pasted code there

Comment: i did it, check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127103/discussion-between-usman-and-fabio-silva-lima).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@usman check it out my jsfiddle based on yours [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57kg5h75/12/)
I used $compile.

```
document.body.innerHTML = "";
var element = $compile(originalContents)($scope);
angular.element(document.body).append(element);
```

Comment: this works perfect but just little one problem, I have multiple divs some are hidden while this work, but after this takes me to default behavior of the page, how would i control that?

Comment: please go and edit my jsfiddle with your hidden fields and let me know ok?

Comment: I have your jsfiddle kidly check that